# how to perform outer merge on multiple DataFrames using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have 125 csv files with same column names. I want to merge all of them (on=column).
I tried the following code, but it didn't work (seems like its running in infinite loop).

```
filelist = glob.glob('*.csv')
dflist = []
for filename in filelist:
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
dflist.append(df)
df_2 = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['gene_id'],how='outer'), dflist)
```

I can't use pd.concat like df_new = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4], axis=1)) since csv files differ in row length.

Is there any other way to perform pd.merge on multiple files??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: if they have the same column names, then pd.concat is ur go to method. what do u mean by the files differ in row length?

Comment: I want to merge all csv files by columns i.e., axis=1. But when I run pd.concat it is giving an error saying array lengths are different.

Comment: it doesnt add up ... if they all have the same columns, y would u want to merge them side by side (that is what axis=1 implies). do u mind sharing say the first five rows of two csvs and show what u want the outcome would be after the merge of those two? based on that, we can possibly figure out what the issue is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
filelist = glob.glob('*.csv')
merged_df = pd.read_csv(filelist[0])

for filename in filelist:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    merged_df = pd.merge(merged_df, df, on = ['gene_id'], how = 'outer')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. For some reason it didn't merge csv files in any particular order. There is no way to say which file was merged where. I tried 'sorted' files still the same issue.